# Cannot add multiple items in list where using pnp batching

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, batch

I use **"sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.4"** Where i trying to create batch for - add multiple items into a list for SharePoint On-Premise .

**This is my code:**

```
let list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyWayBills");
let batch = pnp.sp.web.createBatch();

list.getListItemEntityTypeFullName().then(entityTypeFullName => {

    allCorectTravels.forEach((travel, index) => {

        list.items.inBatch(batch).add({
            Title: String(index)
        }, entityTypeFullName).then(b => {
            console.log(b);
        });

    })

    batch.execute().then(d =>
        console.log("Done")
    );

});
```

[image]

**I have following error:**

[image]

Comment: Working where i use guid of list..

Comment: can you check with removing the `entityTypeFullName` ?

Comment: Can you hard code a value for Title and check. I think it may be due to "String" conversion <Capital S >

Comment: @Goshky there is issue with title, as Title is in non english language,So before passing it to Batch request it must be encoded.